# Android Studio build failed after adding a png file in drawables

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using gradle 2.1.2, compiling with sdk version 23 and build tools version 23.0.3.

My project was compiling properly, but after adding a drawable resource (png file) I got the following message:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:incrementalDebugSupportDex]
>   :app:buildInfoDebugLoader :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :volley:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE :volley:compileLint
>   :volley:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE :volley:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:checkReleaseManifest :volley:prepareReleaseDependencies
>   :volley:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE :volley:compileReleaseAidl
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE :volley:compileReleaseShaders
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE :volley:processReleaseManifest
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72340Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2340Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidVolleyVolleyUnspecifiedLibrary
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4150Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugShaders
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
>   :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > Crunching Cruncher fundo.png failed, see logs

At Event Log I got:

> 13:00:18 Executing tasks: [:app:incrementalDebugSupportDex] 13:00:19
>   Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 1s 93ms

At Build Gradle Console:

> :app:mergeDebugResources AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
>   :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > Crunching Cruncher fundo.png failed, see logs
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1.006 secs

Anyone know how to solve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this in `build.gradle`

```
android {
    ....
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: It worked! Can you tell me what was causing the problem? What is cruncher?

Comment: It might be because of renaming problem of the Image just cut the images and paste any where in the system and open each with the respective editor and save as the same but of PNG format and then copy and paste again to drawable folders. It works for me